# Remove NA in R. (also in ggplot graph)

Tags: r, ggplot2, na

My data looks like

```
Year     ...  Growth_Rate
2011             NA
2012            2.0
2013     ...    3.2
2014            -2.0
2015            1.3
2016     ...    1.9


ggplot(ridership, aes(Year, Bronx$Growth_Rate, group=1, na.rm=TRUE))+   
    geom_bar(stat= "identity", aes(fill=Year)) +  
    scale_y_continuous("Ridership Growth Rate", 
    labels = percent_format())+ geom_point(col='black', size=0.7) + 
    geom_line(col='black', size=0.3) + 
    ggtitle("Ridership Change in Bronx") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

This is the graph. I would like to remove Y2011

---

[image]

Comment: You could filter your data e.g.: ggplot(dplyr::filter(ridership, Year != "Y2011", !is.na(Year)), aes(Year, ...

Answer (score 2):

How about the following code.

**Method 1**

In here, I've preprocessed the missing values by removing them and storing the cleaned data in a separate data frame. Off course, you can save it in the same data frame like, `dat<- na.omit(subset(dat, select = c(Year, Growth_Rate)))`
`

```
# create some dummy data
Year<- c(2011:2016)
Growth_Rate<- c(NA,2.0,3.2,-2.0,1.3,1.9)
dat<- data.frame(Year, Growth_Rate, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# remove missing values
dat.clean<- na.omit(subset(dat, select = c(Year, Growth_Rate)))

# plot it

ggplot(data = dat, aes(Year,Growth_Rate))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", na.rm = TRUE)+
  geom_line(col='black', size=0.3)+
  ggtitle("Ridership Change in Bronx") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

In my perspective, method 1 is easy, works as intended but adds an overhead of a temporary variable to hold the cleaned data.

**Method 2**

By using the `coord_cartesian()`. Again in my opinion, the best use case for this method will be when, you wish to limit the x-axis values.

```
library(ggplot2)
# create some dummy data
Year<- c(2011:2016)
Growth_Rate<- c(NA,2.0,3.2,-2.0,1.3,1.9)
dat<- data.frame(Year, Growth_Rate, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# plot it
ggplot(data = dat, aes(Year,Growth_Rate))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", na.rm = TRUE)+
  geom_line(col='black', size=0.3)+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(2012, 2016))+
  ggtitle("Ridership Change in Bronx") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

The problem with method 2, is when executed it will generate warning message like, `Warning messages: 1: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_path).`

**Method 3**

My grudge with `Method 1`, it was creating an additional temporary variable to store the cleaned data. So I propose method 3;

```
ggplot(data = na.omit(subset(dat, select = c(Year, Growth_Rate))), 
       aes(Year,Growth_Rate))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", na.rm = TRUE)+
  geom_line(col='black', size=0.3)+
  ggtitle("Ridership Change in Bronx") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I think, `Method 3` solves both `my grudge` as well as the `OP question`.

Answer (score 0):

@Ashish answer is good if you only want to not plot `NA` values.

However, you might want to clean your data and to reuse it later without the NA values. Here you go with some filtering using [`is.na`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/NA.html):

```
Year_No_NA <- Year[!is.na(Bronx$Growth_Rate)]
Growth_Rate_No_NA <- Bronx$Growth_Rate[!is.na(Bronx$Growth_Rate)]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It served as `fodder for thought` and likewise I have updated my answer.